# Python Replace Single Quotes Except Apostrophes

Tags: python, regex, substitution, single-quotes

I am performing the following operations on lists of words. I read lines in from a Project Gutenberg text file, split each line on spaces, perform general punctuation substitution, and then print each word and punctuation tag on its own line for further processing later. I am unsure how to replace every single quote with a tag  or  excepting all apostrophes. My current method is to use a compiled regex:

```
apo = re.compile("[A-Za-z]'[A-Za-z]")
```

and perform the following operation:

```
if "'" in word and !apo.search(word):
    word = word.replace("'","\n<singlequote>")
```

but this  ignores cases where a single quote is used around a word with an apostrophe. It also does not indicate to me whether the single quote is abutting the start of a word of the end of a word.

Example input:

```
don't
'George
ma'am
end.'
didn't.'
'Won't
```

Example output (after processing and printing to file):

```
don't
<opensingle>
George
ma'am
end
<period>
<closesingle>
didn't
<period>
<closesingle>
<opensingle>
Won't
```

I do have a further question in relation to this task: since the distinguishment of `<opensingle>` vs `<closesingle>` seems rather difficult, would it be wiser to perform substitutions like

```
word = word.replace('.','\n<period>')
word = word.replace(',','\n<comma>')
```

*after* performing the   replacement operation?

Comment: How do you define a word?

Comment: It's simply a string in an array resulting from words = line.split(). I just split a line on spaces and use \n characters to strip punctuation into tags on new lines when I print out to a file. But I do not want to strip apostrophes because I consider contractions to be suitably-definable "words", in the literal sense.

Comment: The other case (I forgot to mention) is hyphens: I do not want to break up hyphenated words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need to properly replace starting and ending `'`
is **regex**.
To match them you should use:

- `^'` for starting `'` (*opensingle*),
- `'$` for ending `'` (*closesingle*).

Unfortunately, `replace` method does not support regexes,
so you should use `re.sub` instead.

Below you have an example program, printing your desired output
(in *Python 3*):

```
import re
str = "don't 'George ma'am end.' didn't.' 'Won't"
words = str.split(" ")
for word in words:
    word = re.sub(r"^'", '<opensingle>\n', word)
    word = re.sub(r"'$", '\n<closesingle>', word)
    word = word.replace('.', '\n<period>')
    word = word.replace(',', '\n<comma>')
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest working smart here: use [nltk](http://www.nltk.org)'s or another NLP toolkit instead.

[Tokenize words](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html) like this:

```
import nltk
sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
Arthur didn't feel very good."""
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
```

You may not like the fact that contractions like don't are separated. Actually, this is expected behavior. See [Issue 401](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/401).

However, TweetTokenizer can help with that:

```
from nltk.tokenize import tknzr = TweetTokenizer()
tknzr.tokenize("The code didn't work!")
```

If it gets more involved a RegexpTokenizer could be helpful:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
s = "Good muffins cost $3.88\nin New York.  Please don't buy me\njust one of them."
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('\w+|\$[\d\.]+|\S+')
tokenizer.tokenize(s)
```

Then it should be much easier to annotate the tokenized words correctly.

Further references:

- http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html
- http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html

Comment: I appreciate the introduction of a new tool (that I guarantee I will be using, even for this task when I begin performing this tokenizing on more complicated books than Joseph Conrad's Heart of Darkness), but for the present circumstances I feel that NLP is overkill. Of course, I was trying to preform this task using sed and gave up, moving to Python, so perhaps I'll end up on NLP soon.

Comment: @malan you are welcomed. And sure you will; arguably, if you process literature without an NLP toolkit you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I am interested in deploying this toolkit now: can it recognize the difference between open quotes and eliding single quotes (e.g. as that in "Let's get **'em**")?

Answer (score 2):

I think this can benefit from lookahead or lookbehind references. The python reference is https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, and one generic regex site I often reference is https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Your data:

```
words = ["don't",
         "'George",
         "ma'am",
         "end.'",
         "didn't.'",
         "'Won't",]
```

And now I'll define a tuple with regular expressions and their replacements.

```
In [230]: apo = (
    (re.compile("(?<=[A-Za-z])'(?=[A-Za-z])"), "<apostrophe>",),
    (re.compile("(?<![A-Za-z])'(?=[A-Za-z])"), "<opensingle>",),
    (re.compile("(?<=[.A-Za-z])'(?![A-Za-z])"), "<closesingle>", ),
    (re.compile("(?<=[A-Za-z])\\.(?![A-Za-z])"), "<period>",),
)
     ...:      ...:      ...:      ...:      ...:      ...: 
In [231]: words = ["don't",
         "'George",
         "ma'am",
         "end.'",
         "didn't.'",
         "'Won't",]
     ...:      ...:      ...:      ...:      ...:      ...: 
In [232]: reduce(lambda w2,x: [ x[0].sub(x[1], w) for w in w2], apo, words)
Out[232]: 
['don<apostrophe>t',
 '<opensingle>George',
 'ma<apostrophe>am',
 'end<period><closesingle>',
 'didn<apostrophe>t<period><closesingle>',
 '<opensingle>Won<apostrophe>t']
```

Here's what's going on with the regexes:

1. `(?<=[A-Za-z])` is a *lookbehind*, meaning only match (but *do not consume*) if the preceding character is a letter.
2. `(?=[A-Za-z])` is a *lookahead* (still no consume) if the following character is a letter.
3. `(?<![A-Za-z])` is a *negative lookbehind*, meaning if there is a letter preceding it, then it will not match.
4. `(?![A-Za-z])` is a *negative lookahead*.

Note that I added a `.` check within `<closesingle>`, and the order within `apo` matters, because you might be replacing `.` with `<period>` ...

This was operating on single words, but should work with sentences as well.

```
In [233]: onelong = """
don't
'George
ma'am
end.'
didn't.'
'Won't
"""
     ...:      ...:      ...:      ...:      ...:      ...:      ...: 
In [235]: print(
    reduce(lambda sentence,x: x[0].sub(x[1], sentence), apo, onelong)
)

     ...:      ...: 
don<apostrophe>t
<opensingle>George
ma<apostrophe>am
end<period><closesingle>
didn<apostrophe>t<period><closesingle>
<opensingle>Won<apostrophe>t
```

(The use of `reduce` is to facilitate applying a regex's `.sub` on the words/strings and then keep that output for the next regex's `.sub`, etc.)